# How to make a network game on Windows phone (7.5)?

Tags: silverlight, networking, windows-phone, multiplayer

I'm trying to make a simple app using network. For instance, a tic tac toe multiplayers game.
I've read many things but I don't know which is the best. At the beginning, I thought one player makes a server, and other player can connect to the first one over wifi or via internet.

I found these solutions:
- Multicast => only for the local network (wifi)
- XNA => Only via Xbox live ?
- WCF => I never use web services and I don't really know how it works

I want to use an interoperable solution whether I decide to make an Android version.

So, which way or technology should I use ?

Answer (score 3):

For this type of communications you should use [Push Notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh221549.aspx). Using these notifications you can have your game send the move to your servers, you server then sends the notification which gets to the other user via the push services.

Comment: But I don't have server, and I'm looking for a way to make communicate directly the two devices with no passing by a server.

Comment: Are the following items the best way to do ? :

 1. If the user chooses to connect over wifi : search players thanks multicast / If he chooses to the connect over internet : search players thanks to a server
 2. Use UDP socket to play the game

Comment: You're going to need a server to make this work. You can't do direct phone-to-phone AFAIK.